# Can I install and run Redis server with Python?

Tags: django, redis

I am going through Django channel documentation(https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html), at some point it advise to start redis server with docker as mention below,

```
We will use a channel layer that uses Redis as its backing store. To start a Redis server on port 6379, run the following command:

$ docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:5
```

However I skipped using docker so I dont know how to run above command.

Is there any way I can start redis server in virtualenv /pip ?

Comment: where do you installed redis server ? are you working on AWS or any other cloud services  or local server ?

Comment: I am working in Localserver

Comment: then download and install it and run it  - https://redis.io/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can start redis server in virtualenv /pip ?

Well, no.
Redis (itself) is **not** a python package, therefore it can't be installed from `pip` (a python package manager).

From Redis' [official](https://redis.io/topics/introduction) website:

> *Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker*

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04) is a very detailed guide on how to run and config a working Redis server on Ubuntu and CentOS (select the one suitable for you).
And if you're on Arch (I use Arch, btw), you can always visit the [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redis)

Good luck!